# How to remove a specific character from a string, in the middle of string

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that I'm trying to have the data from a field show on the report like "post down" not "post_down" I want to remove the unwanted underscore. there are 3 different condition that come in this field but two has the unwanted underscore. I just need to remove the "__" from to of the 2 condition.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace function to do this. Use the following expression in the textbox's value expression.

```
=REPLACE(Fields!myFieldName.Value, "_", " ")
```

This will replace all instances of an underscore with a space.